# How do you formally prove that a function in several variable is really a function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let say for example that we define $f:\mathbb{R}^{3}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that $f(x,y,z)=(y^{2},xz,xy^{2})$. My informal argument would be just that there is only one object  that can be defined having three real numbers, but I'm just saying this intuitively. How do you prove it formally?

Comment: An extension of the "vertical line test" to 3D?? or not ?...Interesting.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? The definition of a function is something that maps one set into another set.

Comment: @Alex If I wanted to prove that the function $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=x+1$ is really a funciton I would say tha it is because from the definition of $\mathbb{R}$ we prove that the $+$ opereation is well defined, meaning that $+:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is really a function (using Dedeking cuts, Cauchy sequences, etc. or even we can take it as an axiom if we wanted. ).

Comment: @Alex, what you defined is usually called "a relation", and it's in general far from being a function, which requires each input (source) to be related to one and only one output (image).

Comment: What is the alternative? When would a function be not really a function?

Comment: Another way is to show that it is one to one. For instance if the Jacobian matrix is nonsingular, then we have a one to one function. I don't think this answers your question however nor is it a way of proving it formally. Just a trick up my sleeve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, it's useful to analyze a given function as a composition of "smaller" elementary functions. Here, we have the three coordinate functions $f_j : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ($j=1,2,3$) defined by $f_1(x,y,z)=y^2$, $f_2(x,y,z)=xz$ and $f_3(x,y,z)=xy^2$. You could even break these down further. For instance, $f_3$ is the product of the projection $(x,y,z) \mapsto x$ and the function $(x,y,z)\mapsto y^2$, and the product of two real-valued functions with common domain is also a real-valued function.

Finally, given three real-valued functions $f_1,f_2,f_3$ with common domain $\mathbb{R}^3$, we can form the function $f(x,y,z)=(f_1(x,y,z),f_2(x,y,z),f_3(x,y,z))$ with domain $\mathbb{R}^3$ and codomain $\mathbb{R}^3$.

This example kind of clouds the set theory; here's another example. Suppose $f : A \rightarrow B$ and $g : A \rightarrow C$ are both functions. Note that they share the domain $A$. Then we can form a function $h : A \rightarrow B \times C$ where $B \times C$ is the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the sets $B$ and $C$. The function $h$ is defined in terms of $f$ and $g$ via the formula $h(a)=(f(a),g(a))$ for $a \in A$.

I don't believe this construction has a name. In fact, it can be written as a composition of the diagonal map $a \mapsto (a,a)$ going from $A \rightarrow A \times A$ along with the Cartesian product of the functions $f$ and $g$. Note that here I'm talking about the [Cartesian product of two functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cartesian_product_of_functions).

Finally, to glue all of this thinking together, you need to prove that the composition of two functions is actually a function. It sounds silly, but this type of thinking is useful in more advanced classes: the composition of continuous functions is continuous, the composition of differentiable functions is differentiable, the composition of homomorphisms is a homomorphism, etc.

Comment: Altough this doesn't answer my question directly, what you said takes me to the answer I was looking for. Thank you so much. Here is the justification I was looking for: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426824/how-to-prove-a-parametric-relation-to-be-a-function

Answer (score 3):

Let $P=(x_1,y_1,z_1)=(x_2,y_2,z_2)=Q$ then $$x_1=x_2,~~y_1=y_2,~~z_1=z_2$$ then $$y_1^2=y_2^2,~~x_1z_1=x_2z_2,~~x_1y_1^2=x_2y_2^2$$ So $f(P)=f(Q)$. This is very elementary way.

Comment: $\hat{\ddot\smile}$

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, it sounds like you are interested in defining $\mathbb{R}^d$. Afterall, Dedekind cuts are used in constructing the real numbers. If you've defined $\mathbb{R}$ via your favorite axioms (say through Dedekind cuts), then $\mathbb{R}^d$ is defined as all ordered $d$-tuples whose elements take values in $\mathbb{R}$. In other words, say $d=3$ then $(3,1,0.1)=(3,1,0.1)$ but $(3,1,0.1)\neq (0.1,3,1)$.

By definition, $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^d$ maps every point in $\mathbb{R}^d$ to some other point in $\mathbb{R}^d$. In general, the definition of a function is something that maps one set to another set with each input having one output. So in your example, $f(x,y,z)=(y^2,xz,xy^2)$, is perfectly well defined, as each component, say $y^2$, is well defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Your function in each component has some rules in particular, multiplication being one of them, and that's well defined in the field of real numbers from whichever construction you used.